Why is my field value not updating properly in the HTML with my script?
Creating a script that uploads values for me on Workday. However, although the values appear on the screen in their input box, when I click save and continue, which moves me to the next page, I receive these errors:
Errors:
Company: The field Company is required and must have a value.
School or University: The field School or University is required and must have a value.
    let jobNames = ["XXX"]
    let startMonths = ["XXX"]
    let endMonths = ["XXX"]
    let startYears = ["XXX"]
    let endYears = ["XXX"]
    let companyNames = ["XXX"]
    let jobDescriptions = ["XXX"]
    let currentWork = ["False"]
  
    for(let i = 0; i < companyNames.length; i++) {
      let x = document.querySelector(`div[data-automation-id="workExperience-${i + 1}"]`)
      let button;
      if(!x) {
        if(i == 0) {
          button = document.querySelector('button[data-automation-id="Add"]')
        }
        else{
          button = document.querySelector('button[data-automation-id="Add Another"]')
        }
        if (button) {
          button.click()
          await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        }
      }
      let jobInput = document.querySelectorAll(`input[data-automation-id="jobTitle"]`)[i]
      let companyNameInput = document.querySelectorAll(`input[data-automation-id="company"]`)[i]
      let jobDescriptionInput = document.querySelectorAll(`textarea[data-automation-id="description"]`)[i]    
      let monthInput = document.querySelectorAll(`input[data-automation-id="dateSectionMonth-input"]`)[2 * i]    
      let monthInput2 = document.querySelectorAll(`input[data-automation-id="dateSectionMonth-input"]`)[(2 * i) + 1]    
      let yearInput = document.querySelectorAll(`input[data-automation-id="dateSectionYear-input"]`)[2 * i]    
      let yearInput2 = document.querySelectorAll(`input[data-automation-id="dateSectionYear-input"]`)[(2 * i) + 1]    
      if (jobInput) {
        await typeText(jobInput, jobNames[i])
        jobInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
        jobInput.focus()
      }
      if (companyNameInput) {
          await typeText(companyNameInput, companyNames[i])
          //companyNameInput.value = companyNames[i];
          companyNameInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
      }
    if (jobDescriptionInput) {
        jobDescriptionInput.value = jobDescriptions[i];
        jobDescriptionInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
    }
    if (monthInput) {
        monthInput.value = startMonths[i];
        monthInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
        monthInput.focus(); // Focus on the input element
        monthInput.click(); // Simulate click event
        monthInput.click(); // Simulate click event
    }
    if (monthInput2) {
        monthInput2.value = endMonths[i];
        monthInput2.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
        monthInput2.focus(); // Focus on the input element
        monthInput2.click(); // Simulate click event
        monthInput2.click(); // Simulate click event
    }
    if (yearInput) {
        yearInput.value = startYears[i];
        yearInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
        yearInput.focus(); // Focus on the input element
        yearInput.click(); // Simulate click event
        yearInput.click(); // Simulate click event
    }
    if (yearInput2) {
        yearInput2.value = endYears[i];
        yearInput2.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
        yearInput2.focus(); // Focus on the input element
        yearInput2.click(); // Simulate click event
        yearInput2.click(); // Simulate click event
    }    
    }
  }  ```


Have you ever looked into something like puppeteer?

I did a bit, but I think because I'm using a chrome extension, I won't be able to use it properly

It's difficult to debug your script without access to the environment it's running in, or the ability to reproduce the issue.
